# Spring 3 MVC + Hibernate 3.5.x integration - org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, web-applications

I am new to Spring 3 MVC and trying to create a demo working application having integration with hibernate 3.5.x (using annotations).

Below is the error I got in my Eclipse IDE:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.employee.service.EmployeeService com.employee.controller.EmployeeController.employeeService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.employee.dao.EmployeeDAO com.employee.service.EmployeeServiceImpl.employeeDAO; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'employeeDAOImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory com.employee.dao.EmployeeDAOImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [hibernate.cfg.xml] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1055)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:511)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:450)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:287)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:189)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:562)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:871)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:423)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:443)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:459)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:340)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:307)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:127)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1173)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:993)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4421)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:840)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1057)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:463)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:525)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:754)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:595)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
```

Below is my project structure:

[image: Project Structure in Eclipse]

Below are the jar dependencies added in **lib** folder of **web-inf**

[image: Jars Image]

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>Spring3MVCHibernate</display-name>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**Spring-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml  version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.employee" />

<bean id="jspViewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>

<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>
<bean id="propertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
    p:driverClassName="${jdbc.driverClassName}"
    p:url="${jdbc.databaseurl}" p:username="${jdbc.username}"
    p:password="${jdbc.password}" />


<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="configLocation">
        <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
    </property>
    <property name="configurationClass">
        <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

**EmployeeController.java**

```
@Controller
public class EmployeeController {
@Autowired
private EmployeeService employeeService;

@RequestMapping("/index")
public String listContacts(Map<String, Object> map) {

    map.put("contacts", new EmployeeForm());
    map.put("contactList", employeeService.listEmployee());

    return "contacts";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addContact(@ModelAttribute("employeeform")
EmployeeForm employeeForm, BindingResult result) {

    employeeService.addEmployee(employeeForm);

    return "redirect:/index";
}

@RequestMapping("/delete/{employeeId}")
public String deleteContact(@PathVariable("employeeId")
Integer employeeId) {

    employeeService.removeEmployee(employeeId);

    return "redirect:/index";
}
}
```

**EmployeeForm.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="emp")
public class EmployeeForm {
@Id
@Column(name="emp_id")
@GeneratedValue
private int empId;
@Column(name="emp_name")
private String empName;
@Column(name="dept_id")
private int deptId;
@Column(name="age")
private int age;
@Column(name="sex")
private String sex;
    // Getters and Setters
```

**EmployeeService.impl**

```
@Service
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {
@Autowired
private EmployeeDAO employeeDAO;

@Override
@Transactional
public void addEmployee(EmployeeForm employee) {
    employeeDAO.addEmployee(employee);
}

@Override
@Transactional
public List<EmployeeForm> listEmployee() {
    return employeeDAO.listEmployee();
}

@Override
@Transactional
public void removeEmployee(Integer id) {
    employeeDAO.removeEmployee(id);
}   
}
```

**EmployeeDAOImpl.java**

```
@Repository
public class EmployeeDAOImpl implements EmployeeDAO {

@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Override
public void addEmployee(EmployeeForm employee) {
    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().save(employee);
}

@Override
public List<EmployeeForm> listEmployee() {
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from EmployeeForm")
            .list();
}

@Override
public void removeEmployee(Integer id) {
    EmployeeForm employee = (EmployeeForm) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().load(
            EmployeeForm.class, id);
    if (null != employee) {
        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(employee);
    }
}
}
```

**employee.cfg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <mapping class="com.employee.form.EmployeeForm"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

I am new to Spring and have no idea why this problem. Possible reason may be some jar related issue or configuration issue. Please guide.

**EDIT: Adding the contacts.jsp file**

**contacts.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="spring"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Spring 3 MVC Series - Contact Manager</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Contact Manager</h2>

<form:form method="post" action="add.html" commandName="employeeform">

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="empId">
                    <spring:message code="label.empId" />
                </form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="empId" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="empName">
                    <spring:message code="label.empName" />
                </form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="empName" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="deptId">
                    <spring:message code="label.deptId" />
                </form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="deptId" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="age">
                    <spring:message code="label.age" />
                </form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="age" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="sex">
                    <spring:message code="label.sex" />
                </form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="sex" /></td>
        </tr>           
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit"
                value="<spring:message code="label.addemployee"/>" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing hibernate.cfg.xml, although you have a file named employee.cfg.xml, so or you rename the file, or you change the name in spring-servlet.xml